# Error: Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address: 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: django, openshift

After the server is up for some time, it turn's itself down and shows

> Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address: 0.0.0.0:8080

in `openshift log`. In this case restarting option doesn't even work. I also tried rhc app-force-stop and restarting the app, it works for some time and again shows the same error message.

Comment: change port number

Answer (score 1):

It look like other process is using port 8080.

```
$ netstat -anp | grep <port-number>
```

eg.

```
$ netstat -anp | grep 8080
```

by the above you get process name, if you want to use port then you need to stop the process or change the port